# iOS : Is there a way to kill current view controller of NavigationControl before navigating to other view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios

For example current viewcontroller in Navigation Controller is 'A'. Now before or just after navigating to 'B' from 'A', I want to kill 'A'. Is there a way for such a mechanism ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by killing a view controller. Do you mean unload from memory?? You may want to edit your question and explain a little better what you are trying to solve/achieve.

Comment: Yes, by that I meant removing from memory, killing its instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *vcArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[vcArray removeObjectAtIndex: 0];  
self.navigationController.viewControllers = vcArray;
// don't forget to release vcArray if you aren't using ARC
```